# Install Basic UDP Server on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, udp

I'm doing some code testing and one aspect is I need an active **UDP Server**. I've tried looking online how to install one and haven't had much luck.

My only requirement is a UDP Server which I can connect to with my code and retrieve a simple response.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial.

Can someone please assist in this.

My quesiton is to provide a UDP Server i can use.

I see Arcserve UDP Agent (Linux)  but not sure because that might be for backups

I also see netcat but how do i send a response?
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is what Ive tried:

```
root@ubuntuT:/home/jon/gocode/udpserv# echo "pingpong" | nc -u 127.0.0.1 -l 12345 &
[5] 36067
root@ubuntuT:/home/jon/gocode/udpserv# curl http://127.0.0.1:12345
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 12345: Connection refused
```

Comment: Why downvote? I think its pretty clear.

Comment: I added a question

Comment: Curl is HTTP client. HTTP works on TCP protocol. So, trying to test UDP with HTTP client makes no sense. You need to use application that connects via UDP.

Comment: Ups can create a simple UDP listener with `netcat-u -l portnumber`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try netcat:

`nc -u -l 12345 < /dev/zero`

It will start simple server that will send you zero-valued bytes on port 12345.

or:

`echo "pingpong" | nc -u -l 12345`

if you want simple text answer.

Comment: can i have it send a response "pingpong" instead?

Comment: Yes, I've updated answer.

Comment: how do i test this?

Comment: Also with netcat: `nc -u ip.address.of.server 12345`

Comment: Check also this article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-netcat-to-establish-and-test-tcp-and-udp-connections-on-a-vps 
It shows what can you do with netcat.

Comment: I added my attempt in question. Maybe its a firewall issue

Comment: No, it's not firewall issue. Curl is HTTP client, not UDP tool.

Comment: Perfect works greatr.

Comment: One last issue. It seems to be closing the connection after a few queries. I did notice that possibly its because im connecting to udp from a http curl query against go code

Comment: Use `-k` or make a forever loop: `while true; do echo "pingpong" | nc -u -l 12345; done`

Comment: It executes twice then dies with `2018/06/11 13:25:12 read udp 127.0.0.1:60559->127.0.0.1:12345: read: connection refused`

Comment: This loop works that when `nc` quits another instance is starting. For a short while it won't be working before new `nc` starts.

Comment: i see. how much time in between?

Comment: And one last question. This issue wont happen on our dedicated UDP Server. this is due to net cat operationals? The query works fine the first time

Comment: Netcat is simple but powerful tool. If your application will be writen properly it won't happen. Remember that this is just test "server". Read about UDP protocol and network sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You could install dnsmasq to listen on port 53/udp. That is a quick one.

You could start up a python listener on udp.

```
 #/usr/bin/env/python3 
 #Python UDP Listener, listening on localhost 1025, change address 
 # to listen on other ip/port combos. 
 import socket

 sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
 sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 1025))

 while True:
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(65538)
    text = data.decode('ascii')
    print('Connection from Client{} says {}'.format(address, text))
    text = 'Your data was {} bytes long'.format(len(data))
    data = text.encode('ascii')
    sock.sendto(data, address)
```

If you need a client this would work.

```
#/usr/bin/env/python3 
#UDP Client

import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
text = 'Hello World'
data = text.encode('ascii')
sock.sendto(data, ('127.0.0.1', 1025))
data, address = sock.recvfrom(65538) 




#text = data.decode('ascii')
#print('The server {} replied {}'.format(address, text))
```